# Phase shift of damped mass on spring with moving source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators, dissipation

I have a setup with a moving (upwards, downwards) board on which there is a spring mounted on the edge. The spring has a mass $m$ on its end and is damped in some sort of liquid. What methods could I use to calculate the phase shift of the $x(t)$ of the mass when the $y(t)$ (point on which the spring is mounted) is oscillating with a cosine function?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

Set up the $F=ma$ equation for the mass, remembering that the extension of the spring depends on *y* and *x* as well as the weight of the mass, and letting the spring constant (tension per unit extension) be *k*.

Insert $y=y_0\ \cos (\omega t+\phi) $.

Look for a steady state solution of the form $x=x_0\ \cos (\omega t) $.

This is equivalent to inserting $y=y_0\ \cos (\omega t)$ and looking for $x=x_0\ \cos (\omega t-\phi)$, but the algebra is easier.

Things are even easier if you can use complex numbers.